# Visual Studio 2017 - AssemblyInfo.cs not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Today, building my solutions, this problem appear:

> [Error] The file '...\ Projects \ Application \ Application \ obj \ Release \ netcoreapp2.0 \ Application.AssemblyInfo.cs' cannot be found.

I've found solutions for other versions of Visual Studio but not for 2017

Any recommendation on how this can be regenerated?

Comment: Does it exists in the project? If not - create one manually

Comment: It is an auto-generated file, its content is provided by the Project > Properties > Package tab.  Look a the detailed msbuild trace to get hints.

Comment: Rebuild the project. Build -> Rebuild Solution

Comment: @linquize This worked for me. Luis, Probably need to mark this as the correct answer.  For future readers, it's not _Rebuild Project_. It is Rebuild Solution that worked for me.  There's an option for both.

Answer (score 14):

For me, had to create a new assembly file.
Steps:

1. Right-click project properties (not solution).
2. Choose Application tab.
3. Click Assembly Information button. Fields will probably be all empty.
4. Add stuff.
5. Click OK and exit properties.
6. Rebuild.

Comment: I've just hit this problem. My solution has several projects as well as the main exe. Greg's process created the assemblyinfo files OK. I still had problems. I rebuilt each of the projects first then the main one before I could rebuild the solution. Thought this was worth mentioning in case anyone else comes across this.

Answer (score 2):

I also got this error after I Sync-ed to VS Team Service and I got many others errors.
I already tried Greg's suggestion but it didn't work.
But I tried in different way:

1. right click project (not solution)
2. unload project
3. re-load project
4. rebuild solution

and my project run well again.

Comment: For me, this does excatly nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

- Select 'Tools' from the Visual Studio at the top
- Then select 'Assembly Browser'
- The AssemblyInfo of the project is in the list, possibly almost at the top of the list

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue while working on a DLL with a tester project.  Somehow my solution lost track of which project to startup and I had to reset the starter project to my test project for the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

In the solution explorer, find your project. Expand the Properties. Find the 'missing' file, and remove it. Then rebuild your project. That's what worked for me.

note that for whatever reason my AssemblyInfo.cs file had been renamed to SolutionAssemblyInfo.cs. For me, removing the Solution... file and rebuilding created a new AssemblyInfo.cs and I was back in business.

Answer (score 0):

Different versions of vb also make this issue.check out the SVN  by removing the existing one.(confirm the changes get effected else it may lose)