# I am not able to see AssemblyInfo.cs file in visual studio 2k17

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit, nunit-console

I am following a tutorial where he is teaching Selenium with C# Nunit framework, when he creates a new project, a Properties file is generated along with its AssemblyInfo.cs  automatically which is not true in my case, could someone please help achiving the same ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46059213/447156 ?

Comment: Please provide the exact steps you are following to create a new project. Also, a link to the tutorial might be helpful.